# How can we use the partial derivative in such a case?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule, total-variation

Suppose that $g:(0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function of $x$ and $y(x)$, where $x\in (0,+\infty)$ and $y:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ and y is a linear and decreasing function of $x$. If we want to calculate the partial derivative of $g(x,y(x))$ with respect to $x$, then do i need to use the chain rule?

Namely, what is the $\frac{\mathrm dg(x,y(x))}{\mathrm dx}$ in it's general formula if we know only the above information and ton the explicit formula of $g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $y$ is a linear and decreasing function of $x$, we can put
$$
y(x) = a - bx,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are some constants such that $b > 0$.

But as both $x \in (0, +\infty)$ and $y \in (0, +\infty)$ so we must also have
$$
a - bx > 0  \mbox{ for all } x > 0.
$$
and so we must have
$$
0 < x < \frac{a}{b}.
$$

So the requirement that that $x$ and $y$ both vary over the entire range $(0, +\infty)$ cannot be met.

However, barring the above-mentioned unachievable condition, we can put
$$
g\big(x, y(x) \big) = g(x, a-bx)= h(x),
$$
and then
$$
h^\prime(x) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}y^\prime(x) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} (-b) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} -b \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}.
$$